# jQuery .grep() and .filter() not working

Tags: jquery, filter, grep

I have this code:

```
var event = $("‪#‎calendar‬").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
console.log(event);
event = $.grep(event, function(n) {
return n.id == "168" || n._id == "168";
});
console.log(event);
```

The first console.log, logs an array with 12 object. Each object has both .id and ._id indexes and I can see that id 168 does exists.
The second console.log() unfortunately logs an empty array...
What am I doing wrong?

I also tried with .filter()

```
event = event.filter(function(n){
     return n.id === "168";
});
```

But I still get an empty array..

EDIT: Here you can see an image of the first console.log() http://i61.tinypic.com/fmifiu.png
As you can see, 'id' index is a string.
I also tried with both === and == (this should work with both integer and string as it doesn't compare types)

EDIT 2: if I put console.log(n) inside .grep filtering function, nothing is logged to the console. Why??

Comment: There's a difference between `"123"` and `123`. (`123 !== "123"`)

Comment: What does `$("‪#‎calendar‬").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');` return ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle ?

Comment: Here you can see a pic of what the FIRST console.log() logs
http://i61.tinypic.com/fmifiu.png
and as you can see, 'id' is a string

Comment: @Yuri instead of posting an image, run this in your console and c/p the output: `JSON.stringify(event, null, '\t')` You could use pastebin.com if the content is to big for SO

Comment: @null I tried but I get [].

Comment: @Yuri `JSON.stringify($("‪#‎calendar‬").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents'), null, '\t')` Not the `event` array after you have filtered, but before.

Comment: @null this doesn't return a string representation of the event array, but apparently a strign rapresentation of the fullcalendar function or so

Comment: @Yuri `JSON.stringify` returns a string representation of the object/array you sent in as the first arguments: `JSON.stringify([1,     "2"]) === "[1,\"2\"]"`

Comment: I know, that's why I can tell you it doesn't work, because what i get doesn't look like an array, but like a DOM object instead

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a dirty trick (I still don't know why it doesn't work in the normal way).
That's the code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
                var event = events.filter(function(n){

                    return n.id == "168";
                });

                console.log(event);
            }, 100);
```

It works in this way, but, why?

Comment: Because when you try to access the clientEvents there isn't any yet, but when the above timeout is called the array is filled.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious, but why? The clientEvents function returns an array from a cached variable, so there shouldn't be any delay in returning it